# What if someone transfers his/her asset to someone?

Tags: property

Imagine that there's a person who has asset. If that person transfers his asset to someone, might he get his asset back? Or can he prepare a protocol as he will get his asset back when he wants?

Regards!

Comment: This is basically asking "explain contracts".

Comment: @Stackstuck Indeed, yes. I mean Is it possible to prepare a protocol that he will get his asset back when he wants?

Comment: _Why?_  Why are you asking for an explanation of contracts?  @Lagranian

Comment: @Stackstuck No, sir. I'm not asking for an explanation of contracts. I'm asking that it is possible or not. I mean I want to prepare a protocol that I can get my asset when I want.

Comment: ...Yes, it's called a contract.

Comment: What if a person whom I've transferred my asset doesn't give it back? Must he/she give it back?

Comment: Then you sue them, probably, but it depends on the contract.  In any case, this question is far too broad...And this comment chain is too long.

Comment: @Stackstuck Is it mostly being done during the divorce? to kidnap money.

Comment: _What_ does divorce have to do with this?

Comment: For example, I want to divorce from my wife and have children. However, I don't want to give them money. If I prepare a protocol that I can transfer my money to someone, I will be seeming like I don't have any money. Got it? It was an example.

Comment: One: I think that's fraud.  Two: That's an entirely different question.

Comment: @Stackstuck Exactly. However, Does it come possible to you?

Comment: No.  I'm done here.

Comment: Not enough facts to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible to create a mutual agreement under which one party transfers property to another person, including various conditions under which the recipient would be required to return the property to the originating party, among possibly infinite other ways.

In transfer of real estate, for instance, there is also such a thing as a conditional deed in the form of "fee simple determinable" or maybe also "fee simple  subject to condition subsequent", in the common law, in which title reverts, or may revert, to the grantor according to various specified conditions in the transfer deed.

As a general rule, if a person attempts to transfer their property to others in violation of the local laws (e.g., for fraud on creditors), a court (e.g., in the USA) may have the power to rescind the transfer "as a matter of law", placing the property within reach of the originating party's creditors.  Similar rules may apply in situations related to rescission in divorce, elder-care, bankruptcy, and the like.

Of course, numerous jurisdictions have no "common law" at all (being governed under, "civil law", for one) and even most US states have enacted statutes that supersede the common law in various ways.

Comment: There was a case in the UK, where a man admitted on a radio show that he was cheating on his wife. She heard it, put his beloved £30,000 car up for sale on eBay for £1 with "Buy me now" button, the sale went through, and his car was gone. The sale was legal and irrevocable. If it seems to good to be true, sometimes it isn't.